# Using libsodium.crypto_pwhash (Argon2) in Node

Tags: node.js, libsodium, argon2-ffi

I am having trouble getting `crypto_pwhash_str` working in my Node project. I imported the libsodium-wrappers-sumo and libsodium-sumo libraries properly and am able to call other functions with success. My call to the problematic function looks like this:

```
sodium.crypto_pwhash_str(password, 3, 4096, 'text')
```

In this case, password is just a string object with the letter 'a'.

When I run the debugger and try to figure out what is going wrong I get to this internal block of code:

```
if ((libsodium._crypto_pwhash_str(hashed_password_address, password_address, password_length, 0, opsLimit, 0, memLimit) | 0) === 0) {
  var ret = libsodium.Pointer_stringify(hashed_password_address);
  _free_all(address_pool);
  return ret;
}
_free_and_throw_error(address_pool);
```

It fails to enter the for loop and the call to `_crypto_pwhash_str()` evaluates to `-1` for some reason.

Does anyone have any experience with this library or can help me figure out what I am doing wrong. Fairly new to Node so I am quite lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. I (for some silly reason) thought that `memlimit`, which I set to 4096, was measured in MB, Apparently it is measured in kilobytes and has a MINIMUM value acceptable of 32768 (32 MB). It now works!